# How to access the query string value pass to a modal popup by an href by using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

The normal way to access a query string vallue by cf is #url.qs_name# but when the particular url opens a modal pop up we cannot use url.qs_name to read a query string value . What do i should use in this kind of a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using CFWINDOW to create your modal window? If so then you can certainly access the URL scope from within the modal window:

```
<!--- Create a modal window --->
<cfajaximport tags="cfwindow" />
<cfwindow name="modal_window" title="Modal Window" modal="true" center="true" width="900" height="520" resizable="false" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function open_modal(val)
{
    var url = "modal_window.cfm?qs_name=" + val;

    ColdFusion.navigate(url, "modal_window");
    ColdFusion.Window.show("modal_window");
}
// -->
</script>
```

The variable #url.qs_name# will then be available in modal_window.cfm.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you are making an ajax call to load the content of the modal window.

If you are loading the content via ajax when opening the window, then you can pass the query string as usual when calling the cfm file on the server.

But if you are just opening a window with preloaded content, and not loading it dynamically via ajax on opening, then you will need to access any values using javascript.